# org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute query

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, hibernate, deadlock

I am using in my application  Hibernate 3 and JBoss.

Randomly in my application LockAcquisition occurs.

How to deal with it ?

here is the stack trace (but every time it is not coming at this place it is varying)

```
13:49:45,941 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)
13:49:49,962 WARN  [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4) SQL Error: 1205, SQLState: 40001
13:49:49,963 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4) Transaction (Process ID 90) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun t
he transaction.
13:49:49,967 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4) Error Occurred While loadActivitiesFromActivitySchedule method.
13:49:49,972 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4) org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute query
13:49:49,973 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:82)
13:49:49,975 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
13:49:49,977 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2223)
13:49:49,978 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
13:49:49,980 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
13:49:49,981 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:94)
13:49:49,983 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1569)
13:49:49,984 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283)



13:49:50,025 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4) Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Transaction (Process ID 90) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun t
he transaction.
13:49:50,027 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:368)
13:49:50,028 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2820)
13:49:50,029 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2258)
13:49:50,030 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.isDataInResultSet(TdsCore.java:796)
13:49:50,030 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsResultSet.<init>(JtdsResultSet.java:134)
13:49:50,031 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQLQuery(JtdsStatement.java:483)
13:49:50,032 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:776)
13:49:50,034 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
13:49:50,035 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)
13:49:50,036 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
13:49:50,037 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
13:49:50,038 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
13:49:50,038 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-4)      ... 42 more
```

Comment: This error basically means while the above statement was to be executed, the same db was locked and so the statement could not be executed. You need to identify what queries are executing on the same db that is causing the lock